# git push error when trying to copy a folder from one repo to another

Tags: git, github

I have copied a folder from one repo to my local git repository using steps mentioned in - http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

Now I have the required folder and all the history attched to it in my local . 
At the end when I am trying to push the changes using "git push" command , it its giving me error - you can push only your changes

I tried changing the config and prehooks are disabled , However nothing is working .

Please suggest how I can push the changes to the server .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git push origin <your_branch_name> --force
```

Comment: I tried that , however it is not working and giving me same error

Comment: What are the steps you followed before `git push`? If you followed the steps mentioned [here](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history), can you write the results of `git config --list` command from inside the folder that you are trying to push. The possible reasons you are getting *you can only push your changes* error is because (a) you are pushing it in incorrect repo or (b) you are pushing the whole repo instead of just pushing the changes i.e. after `git add .` and `git commit -m "your message" ` commands